# Preflight request doesn´t pass access check : It does not have HTTP OK status

Tags: apex, api, integration, cors

When the customer is trying to connect with Salesforce it get Preflight 400 error.
Without web-security-disable ON it is working as expected, also in Postman it is working as expected but with web-security-disable OFF it gives us an preflight error before authentication (before getting the access token).
Since the auth is handled out of the box by Salesforce we are unable to handle the preflight method request. We have also whitelisted the URLs in the CORS Security Setup.

Error message that we get : **Access to XML HttpRequest 'url' has been blocked by CORS Policy. Response to preflight request doesn't pass Access Control Check. It does not have HTTP ok request status.**

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your question does not include a statement of a goal, has unclear description of a problem and does not show code or configuration.

Comment: Hi @identigral thank you for your response. Configuration that we´ve added is that we whitelisted the url which should communicate with our backend (Setup --> CORS) . 
Regarding the code : this preflight request never actually allow to trigger any of our code (we set up the debug logs but they were never triggered). On the other  hand when we tried this in Postman it was working and the debug logs were showing.
Maybe we have missed some Salesforce setup configuration settings that is affecting CORS. Thanks